# count number of times a url is visited

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

there are few anchor tags (links on my page). I want to keep a count of how many times each link is visited and display only the ones which are mostly visited.

Is there a way to do that .?

Or

to count how many times a URL is visited is also fine.

Comment: You need to store the count on the server or to an external service. No way to do it with JavaScript+HTML only.

Comment: What server do you have? Can you use any programming language?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Using on your own server

You need a server application, which uses programming language like PHP to store and modify counts. If you have a PHP Server, there's a simple hit counter you can do with this:

```
<?php
    $count_my_page = ("hitcounter.txt");
    $hits = file($count_my_page);
    $hits[0] ++;
    $fp = fopen($count_my_page , "w");
    fputs($fp , "$hits[0]");
    fclose($fp);
    echo $hits[0];
?>
```

#### Using a Remote Service

If you don't have the option of hosting a script on your server, you can use some hosted solutions like:

- [Hit Counter HTML Code](http://www.hit-counter-html-code.com/tumblr-hit-counters.html)
  Well, the name says it all, you can give the counter an Initial start count of your counter !!.
- [ewebsitecounter](http://www.ewebsitecounter.com/) has the fanciest icons among all tumblr hit counters available for free. You can choose from many different layouts, including animals and seasonal pics.
- [Hit-Counter](http://hit-counter.info/), definitely the most popular tumblr online counter outthere. Please be careful when entering the details for your blog since the site it’s full of ads.
- [Online Users Counter](http://freehostedscripts.net/onlinecounter/)
- [Supercounters](http://www.supercounters.com/) - free hit counter,users online counter flag counter visitor map for website blog and tumblr
- [HitWebCounter](http://www.hitwebcounter.com/) - The most widely used Free internet Counter.

Comment: Thanks praveen I realize this has to be done at the server side.

Comment: @NandanChaturvedi Glad that I was able to help you bro! `:)` Please do try Google Analytics. It is worth! `:D`

Answer (score 1):

You can use google analytic tools for such information you can find more over [here](http://www.google.com.pk/analytics/) Alternatively you can put your logic in server side to count the hits each url in your website is getting.

Answer (score 0):

You can user cookies, similar to this one.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            if (!$.cookie("urlCookie")) {
                var url = document.referrer;
                var match = url.indexOf("localhost");
                if (match != -1) {
                    $.cookie("urlCookie", url);
                    $("#title").html(url);
                }
            } else {
                $("#title").html($.cookie("urlCookie"));
            }
});



<h1 id="title"></h1>
```

Comment: No, then you would need to keep track of all the users that visited your site, and still have no access to the information in their cookies. And what happens when the user deletes a cookie?

Comment: if you need to do so then you have to use third party to track and save them, like google analytic or any other service.

Comment: You have to count how many times a URL is visited, not how many times a user visited a URL!

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would use server side code or analytics to acheive this, but since you've tagged as a HTML5/JavaScript question, you could do something along the lines of:

```
if ( localStorage ) {
    jQuery( 'a' ).click( function () {

        var urls = localStorage.getItem( 'urls' );

        urls = ( urls != null ) ? JSON.parse( urls ) : {};

        urls[ this.href ] = urls[ this.href ] || 0;
        urls[ this.href ]++;

        urls = JSON.stringify( urls );

        localStorage.setItem( 'urls', urls );

    });
}
```

More information here http://www.html5rocks.com/en/features/storage

Comment: This tracks how many times *one* user has visited the page. The question was about how many times a page has been visited *in total*.